# How to remove an custom javadoc tag from Intellij-IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I accidentally created a custom javadoc tag in Intellij-IDEA by clicking the light bulb. Does anybody know how to delete it again?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[image: Settings | Inspections | Declaration has javadoc problems | Additional JavaDoc Tags]

Comment: Thanks. would not have found it myself.

Answer (score 5):

This is for `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5`.
[image]
Remove the tag from the `Additional Javadoc Tags` field.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Intelij IDEA 2018.2

File -> Settings... -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java -> Javadoc -> Declaration has Javadoc problems

At the right of the window there is "*Options*" field click blue **Reset** text. And click OK. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

This is for IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1

[image: This is for IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1]