# Remove JavaDoc Tag Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm looking for a way to delete an added JavaDoc tag.
The only solution on StackOverflow was from 2010 and did not help me because Intellij has updated and the menu settings are no longer the same.

If anyone could tell me how to remove it, that would be great.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461213/how-to-remove-an-custom-javadoc-tag-from-intellij-idea) was the question from '10.

Edit 2: When you add a JavaDoc tag, and Intellij doesn't detect it as a valid tag, you can right click to add it to your saved JavaDoc tags.

I am looking for a way to remove my saved tags.

Comment: If you could provide more detail about what your problem is, that would be great as well :) I suggest you take a screenshot and add a link to the question/answer that could not help you, so that this is not tagged as duplicate

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Read the first sentence again man

Comment: Okay, now I had a look at the linked issue. But again your question is lacking information: Why does the answer to that issue "did not help me"? AFAICS the answer given there is still perfectly valid.

Comment: @StephenFriedrich I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from the linked issue is still valid, only the path to that settings has changed slightly.
Anyway, it is easiest if you just use the provided search: Use "File -> Settings", then type "javadoc problems" in the search field in the upper left.

You will then easily find "Editor -> Inspections", with the inspection "Java -> Javadoc issues -> Declaration has Javadoc problems" at the right.