# IntelliJ IDEA quick documentation don't show javadoc with custom tag

Tags: intellij-idea

I add custom tag `@mbggenerated`, but the quick documentation shows nothing.
How to do?

Comment: Are you looking for this then ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461213/how-to-remove-an-custom-javadoc-tag-from-intellij-idea?

Comment: @manfromnowhere no，although you created one custom tag, but it didn't appear in quick documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's [not supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200852) at the moment.

Comment: The Tag is auto-generated, Can I ignore it and regard it as a general document? What I want is its text.

Comment: No, you can't do that until the linked issue is fixed.